# What's the simplest forwarding class definition in Python?

Tags: python

I'd like to implement a forwarding class in Python, implementing some base class, which takes in its constructor another implementation of the same base class and forwards through to that class for each method in the base class.

This can be useful to provide a customization point, adding in caching for certain methods, logging around each call site, and the like.

It's simple to write this manually. Given this base class:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def method_a(self, *args):
        pass

    @property
    def prop_b(self):
        pass

    def method_c(self, a, b, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Here's a straightforward forwarding implementation.

```
class ForwardBaseClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, underlying_implementation):
        self._impl = underlying_implementation

    def method_a(self, *args):
        return self._impl.method_a(*args)

    @property
    def prop_b(self):
        return self._impl.prop_b

    def method_c(self, a, b, **kwargs):
        return self._impl.method_c(a, b, **kwargs)
```

The downside of just writing the code is that there's a lot of boilerplate code, and that code has to be written for each method. As methods are added to the base class, similar code has to be added into the forwarding class; and if changes are desired in how the class does its forwarding, they have to be spread through all the methods. (Imagine, for instance, that we wanted to change the class so that it took a context manager which it used around each call.)

Is there a short, Pythonic way to do this, either in the base language, with built-in modules, or with some reliable module on PyPI?

Desired features:

- Exact method signatures

  - The forwarded signature should match the base class
  - No `*args, **kwargs` on every signature
- Methods with the `@property` decorator are wrapped properly
- `__<method>__` methods, if they exist, are wrapped properly
- No extra cost per method call over the straight-forward implementation
- `dir(instance)` does the same thing as a straight-forward implementation

Nice to have:

- Error messages where the base class doesn't meet some necessary criteria
- Meaningful docstrings
- Ability to derive from the resulting object
- Methods with the `@staticmethod` decorator are forwarded to the class of the passed-in implementation
- Methods with the `@classmethod` decorator are forwarded to the class of the passed-in implementation
- `__init__` and `__new__` are not forwarded

Places where there is likely additional complexity:

- Base class has a metaclass
- Base class has multiple base classes of its own
- Some of the more esoteric `__<method>__`s and their semantics

Don't really care about:

- Multiple base classes
- Custom descriptor decorators other than `@property`, `@staticmethod`, and `@classmethod`
- Modifications to the base class after forwarding class creation

Comment: you could use `getattr` to forward everything except `__init__` and `__new__` (and other things you do not want) to `self._impl`. this may not have all your desired properties though...

Comment: I doubt there is a short, Pythonic or otherwise way to do this, frankly!

Comment: In particular the "No extra cost per method call over the straight-forward implementation" seem to be hard to satisfy, at least if you want to catch all kind of odd situations. The solution you suggests for example redirects the calls to the `self._impl` object - this extra call carries some extra cost per call. Also the requirement for `dir(instance)` to work means some more work that could hurt per call cost.

Answer (score 1):

just to clarify my comment: what i mean is +/- this (needs more work though... and again: may not satisfy all your requirements):

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def method_a(self, *args):
        pass

    @property
    def prop_b(self):
        pass

    def method_c(self, a, b, **kwargs):
        pass

class ForwardBaseClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, underlying_implementation):
        self._impl = underlying_implementation

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # here you may have to exclude thigs; i.e. forward them to
        # self.name instead for self._impl.name
        try:
            return getattr(self._impl, name)
        except AttributeError:
            # do something else...

bc = BaseClass()
fbc = ForwardBaseClass(bc)
print(fbc.prop_b)
print(fbc.method_c(1,2,c=5))
print(dir(fbc))
```

note that due to [python name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_Python) you will not be able to access members starting with `__` this way.

Comment: This won't work for most `__special__` methods, as those are looked up in slots, and never through `__getattr__`. You might also want to implement `__dir__` to list the wrapped object's attributes.

Comment: i agree (and have mentioned one of your points already). but as long as there is no reaction from the OP i will not go further with this idea...

Comment: I think my previous comment came out more harsh than I had intended it to be. The approach you show is really the best one in general, the questioner's criteria are fairly silly.

Comment: no worries! your comment is absolutely correct and to the point and in no way harsh or offending.

Comment: @Blckknght, I am always astounded that people so boldly state a need to be "fairly silly" just because they cannot think of/foresee one. Let me give you an example - backwards compatibility/regression testing which can be controlled programmatically.